# Using knockout destroy() with django deserializer

Tags: django, knockout.js

In knockout.js there is a function called destroy() [See bottom of this page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)
It says that it is useful for Rails developers as it adds a _destroy attribute to a object in an observerable array

Im using django and trying to use the same function to know which objects to delete from my database - and as far as i understand a django deserialized object only contains the and pk what is in the fields object

this is what the json looks like:

```
{"pk": 1,
 "model": "eventmanager.datetimelocgroup",
 "fields": {"event": 10},
 "_destroy": "true"
}
```

As of now i have very ugly but working code - i was wondering if there is any shorter way to detect if a deserialized object had a destroy flag

my current code looks like this

```
ra = []
removejson = json.loads(eventslist)
for i,a in enumerate(removejson):
    if '_destroy' in a:
        ra.append(i)
for index,event in enumerate(serializers.deserialize("json", eventslist)):
    if index in ra:
        try:
            e = Event.objects.get(id = event.object.pk)
            e.delete()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
    else:
        event.save()
```

I was wondering if there is a better way than going through the json multiple time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This oneliner should work (please understand it before trying it out):

```
Event.objects.filter(
    id__in = [
        x['fields']['event'] for x in json.loads(eventslist) if '_destroy' in x
    ]
).delete()
```

Comment: that would work (and is quite brilliant) - however that would require me to first save all the objects and then delete - rather than finding out in the normal      for e in deserializer.deserialize(json) event loop (the reason i need it in the event loop is because i make changes to the objects before they get saved which is dependent on the order in the json array)